# char* in a gpointer sends a string in a strange encoding

Tags: c, callback, gtk, char

I have the following problem.
When I pass a `char` argument defined as `char id_rest[25];` in a form of a `gpointer` in a `g_signal_connect` function this way:

```
  g_signal_connect (G_OBJECT (button_pas_save), "clicked", G_CALLBACK (save),  (gpointer) id_rest);
```

When I printf it in the callback function which in this case is `save` what I get looks like a string in a different encoding. For example when I pass `AAA` I get `�`.

I've tryied to use a `char*` pointer and `malloc` and it changed nothing. But what is strage, when instead of passing a variable I pass just a string beetween `""` it works fine. For example:

```
  g_signal_connect (G_OBJECT (button_pas_save), "clicked", G_CALLBACK (save),  (gpointer) "AAA");
```

Sends me `AAA`.

Here is my printf in a `save` callback:

```
    printf("%s\n", (char*) id);
```

And `id` is a `gpointer` argument.
I've also tryed using a `gchar` instead of `char`, it didn't changed anything neither.

I'm out of ideas. Please help.

EDIT:

Filling the variable is done by a different function called `get_id`, here as you can see I'm testing this action with a `printf` and the result is fine, it's really after the callback it sends something strange.

```
  get_id(con, selection, "pass", id_rest);
  printf("%s\n", id_rest);
```

Comment: What happens when you make `id_rest` a global variable?

Comment: then it seems to work fine, why is that??

Comment: It means @J_D is probably right. That the stack variable has gone out of scope, so your callback is printing invalid memory.

Comment: I see, thank you very much guys for your feedback. I need to educate myself more on this matter. :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Is `id_rest` stored on the stack? It has probably gone out of scope when the callback is called, and maybe `g_signal_connect` does not copy it but merely stores a pointer to it.

**EDIT**

By rereading the question, I notice that you have also tried allocating from the heap using malloc, so it does not seem to be because the array has gone out of scope (unless you called `free` before the callback was called)

Comment: Exactly. Thanks anyway for the feedback.